# MySql regexp match all characters

Tags: php, mysql, regex, codeigniter

I am matching a regexp in MySQL as follows:

```
$this->db->where('bottom_id REGEXP', $bottom);
```

The values of $bottom comes from a array:

```
$bottom_key = array('EG','LE','KG','IS|BO|COA|ARG|PAW|HSE','JG|KH|BR|LL|MO|RA', 'JGS|KHS|BRS|LLS|KHC|BRC|TY|MOS|RAS', 'LEO|EGS');
```

When I run the query 'JG|KH|BR|LL|MO|RA' and 'JGS|KHS|BRS|LLS|KHC|BRC|TY|MOS|RAS' duplicate some of the results i.e. JGS is selected from the JG value.

How do I force an exact match of the values so that JG will only match JG and not JGS?

The data table looks as follows:

```
|------
|id|order_id|product_id|upper_id|bottom_id|create_date|del_date|ref_no|comm_code
|------
|81|17|6151|HSA       |IS        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-10-15|NULL|NULL
|82|17|7441|BHE       |IS        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-09-15|NULL|NULL
|83|17|7501|MUA       |IS        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-07-15|NULL|NULL
|84|17|7137|KDB       |IS        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-07-07|NULL|NULL
|85|17|7137|KDD       |IS        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-08-15|NULL|NULL
|86|17|6613|PAA       |KG        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-10-15|NULL|NULL
|87|17|7315|CDA       |KG        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-07-07|NULL|NULL
|88|17|7525|COA       |KG        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-07-07|NULL|NULL
|89|17|7525|COA       |KG        |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-09-15|NULL|NULL
|90|17|1600|JGC       |MOS       |0000-00-00 00:00:00|2016-08-15|PD65929|NULL
```

Comment: What about `/(JG[^S])/` ?

Comment: can you provide raw data sample and expected result?

Comment: Made a simple test here: https://regex101.com/r/eM8sR5/1

Comment: Alex, I'm building groupings. Using the | as an or for the where clause. So for [3] of the array it would be select where $bottom = IS or BO or COA or ARG or PAW or HSE

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$bottom_key = array('^EG$','^LE$','^KG$','^(IS|BO|COA|ARG|PAW|HSE)$','^(JG|KH|BR|LL|MO|RA)$', '^(JGS|KHS|BRS|LLS|KHC|BRC|TY|MOS|RAS)$', '^(LEO|EGS)$');
```

The regexp symbol `^` indicates the starting of the string and `$` its end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a strict match by putting $ after JG ie, JG$, which means the matching string should end with G. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off with a single `IN` clause, not an array of regexps.

```
bottom_id IN ('EG','LE','KG','IS','BO','COA','ARG','PAW','HSE','JG',...)
```